# How to remove pgAdmin 4 old version?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

On my Windows 10, I used the Windows installer made by EnterpriseBD and installed postgresql 11.1. It however seems to have came with version 3.5 of pgAdmin 4. So, I downloaded pgAdmin 4 version 4.0 and installed it on my PC. Now both the two versions exist on the PC.

Did I do anything wrong during installation? How can I remove the version 3.5 of pgAdmin 4 properly?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks Kubra.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to Programs and Features -> postgresql 11 and click uninstall. A window opens and allows you to select uninstalling whole postgresql or individual components. You can select pgadmin from there.

Hope it helps :)